# How to get attribute content between a specific class by php

Tags: attributes, tags

here is a input code:

```
$str='
<div class="_53d _53q">Not necessary data</div>
<div class="tagWrapper">
<i style="background-image: url(https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/p206x206/401581_10201210435645736_1028078736_n.jpg);" class="uiMediaThumbImg"></i>
<div class="taggerOverlay hidden_elem"><div class="left blackwash"></div></div>
</div>

<div class="_53d _53q">Not necessary data</div>
<div class="_53d _53q">Not necessary data</div>
<div class="tagWrapper">
<i style="background-image: url(https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/p206x206/486115_10200477972538937_146909394_n.jpg);" class="uiMediaThumbImg"></i>
<div class="taggerOverlay hidden_elem"><div class="left blackwash"></div></div>
</div>
<div class="_53d _53q">Not necessary data</div>
';
```

Now i want the output as :

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/p206x206/401581_10201210435645736_1028078736_n.jpg
        [1] => https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/p206x206/486115_10200477972538937_146909394_n.jpg
    )
```

I want to get all of the images links in-between the `" <div class="tagWrapper"> <i "` attributes and discards all of the other contents. Please help me to give a php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse html.

You can improve this code by adding an extra level of searching over the `<i>` elements, but I thought the `<i>` tag was uncommon enough.

Once inside the style property, I used string parsing. It should be improved to be more versatile, but this should get you a lot closer to your goal.

```
    $arr = array();

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($str);
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('i') as $node) {
        if($node->hasAttribute('style')) {
            $nodes = explode(":",trim($node->getAttribute('style')), 2);
            if(trim($nodes[0]) === 'background-image') {
                $pos = strpos(trim($nodes[1]), "url");
                if($pos !== false) {
                    $arr[] = substr(trim($nodes[1]), 4, -2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```